# Error while binding tkinter list box binding with a method in same class (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, listbox

I have written a class to create Listbox objects, I want to bind the list box with a method in the same class but I am getting attribute error. what am I doing wrong here??

```
class ListObj(tkinter.Listbox):

    def __init__(self, window, cname, r, c, rs, cs, sticky, bg, padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=0, ipady=0, **kwargs):
        self = tkinter.Listbox(window)
        self.grid(row=r, column=c, rowspan=rs, columnspan=cs, sticky=sticky, padx=padx, pady=pady,
                  ipadx=ipadx, ipady=ipady)
        self.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', self.on_select)

    def on_select(self):
        pass
```

output:

```
AttributeError: 'Listbox' object has no attribute 'on_select'
```

Comment: You are missing `super().__init__()` under your `__init__` method. That said you will also need to delete `self = tkinter.Listbox(window)`

Answer (score 1):

The line causing the problem is `self = tkinter.Listbox(window)`. You do not need to tell self it is a listbox because it already inherits listbox in the class definition.

Do this instead:

```
class ListObj(tkinter.Listbox):
    def __init__(self, window, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', self.on_select)

    def on_select(self):
        pass
```

You should use grid on the reference variable outside of the class. It is not the best option to use a geometry manager from inside of a class.

```
var_name = ListObj(var1, var2, var2 ...)

var_name.grid(configs....)
```